# Web Application calling

Tags: php

I did not find a better title if you have a better one please correct me.

My web application root looks like this:

```
- Controllers
-- User
--- Settings
--- Profile
-- Page
--- Edit
--- Show
- objects (models)
-- User
-- Page
- templates (views)
-- User
--- Settings
ect...
```

Now My Question is should i create a index file that handles everything?

Real URL -> mod_rewrite URL

```
index.php?module=user&action=settings  ->  /user/settings/
```

Or let mod_rewrite handle everything?

```
Controllers/User/Settings.php  ->  /user/settings/
```

I mean with a index file it's much comfortable, but which one is faster? also which one is faster under high traffic?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance differential will be microscopic for any but the highest traffic apps, and doing your routing in PHP instead of mod_rewrite will be easier to maintain and more flexible.